# Can't run command from Process.Start

Tags: c#, .net

I can run this fine from the command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen  C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg
```

Image opens no problem.

However, when I try and do this:

```
exe = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen  C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg";
Process.Start(exe);
```

I get a

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

I have tried with quotes on both the command line and C#, and neither work with them.  According to an answer I read on SO recently the last part should not be quoted.

What's going on?

Comment: You might need to wrap the last param with quotes as well, since part of the path contains a space.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I read a post on here somewhere that said the last part should not be in quotes, and the command line version doesn't work with quotes around the last item either.

Comment: Try it anyways ;-)  Also you can run Process Monitor to see which specified file cannot be found, that might give a hint.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out one has to pass the command and arguments separately:

```
exe = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe";
arguments = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen  C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg";
Process.Start(exe, arguments);
```

Comment: is this suppose to work if it's a file directory is in a form of a URL?

Comment: @user1166085 I don't think so.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx, Remarks section:  'If the address of the executable file to start is a URL, the process is not started and null is returned.'